# Understanding Q-learning for continuous actions

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am reading the [paper](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.00748&ved=2ahUKEwjlxsSAuLDdAhUQLlAKHbluCccQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw1r3hajYTSjEkO_wMK4mGsI) on *Normalized Advantage Functions* for continuous Q-learning and I am having trouble understanding why the advantage function takes this particular form:

[image]

Why is the Advantage function, ($A$) quadratic in actions ($u$)? What are the purposes of $P$ and $\mu $? I am completely lost at why the advantage function takes this form and how it is justified.

**Edit:** so I can see that when $u=\mu$ , $A$ is maximized which is handy but why do we need $P$ - after all $\mu$ would still maximise $A$ without the $P$ right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It adds on the assumption that the advantage / Q-function is quadratic -- even though this might not hold true in all cases, it does have the advantage of making learning much easier especially in high dimensional spaces. (To be clear, it's not a mathematical claim that $A$ is quadratic, but rather the authors model $A$ using a neural network whose outputs are constrained to this quadratic form).

The authors elaborate on the implications of restricting the advantage function to be quadratic in section 8.3.

> We can thus intuitively interpret NAF as doing variational
>   inference to fit a Gaussian to a distribution, and it has
>   mode-seeking behavior. Empirically such behavior en-
>   ables NAF to learn smoother and more precise controllers,
>   as most effectively illustrated by three-joint reacher and
>   peg insertion experiments, and substantial improvements in
>   terms of convergence speeds in many other representative
>   domains explored in the main paper.

Comment: Why do we need P though?

Comment: @Mellow the general form of a quadratic function is $f(x) = x^TAx$ -- you need $A$ in order to be able to express the full space of quadratic functions.

Comment: Thanks. I have selected your answer as the correct answer. Unfortunately I cannot +1 your answer as I don't have enough points (<15) to be able to do that - stack rules :S